# MongoDB driver and cluster

Tags: java, mongodb, sharding

I am moving from a single mongodb instance to a sharded cluster with 3 replica sets, 3 config servers and 1 mongos instance. Each replica set in turn has three mongod instances.

I'm looking for high availability when I am adding documents to the collection. What  should I connect to from my Java program? Should I connect to mongos or mongod from any replica set?

Can you please let me know ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sharded environment, your application(s) should always connect to mongos instance(s).

From your application's perspective mongos instance behaves as any other MongoDB instance.

Even if you have a non-sharded database or a collection that resides on a single shard, it's recommended that you use mongos for all operations (even if those operations don't impact sharded data).

You can read more details on [Sharded Cluster Query Routing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/) man pages.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect to the mongos and let it route your requests as appropriate.